# How to replace element in multidimensional array in ruby

Tags: ruby, arrays, replace, multidimensional-array

I am having some difficulty with my code and I am hoping for some insight:

I have a 2d array for a board and I am attempting to replace a number with "X" when called, but am having struggles achieving this.

```
class BingoBoard

  def initialize
    @bingo_board = Array.new(5) {Array (5.times.map{rand(1..100)})}
    @bingo_board[2][2] = 'X'
  end

  def new_board
  @bingo_board.each{|row| p row}
end

def ball
  @letter = ["B","I","N","G","O"].shuffle.first
  @ball = rand(1..100)
  puts "The ball is #{@letter}#{@ball}"
end


def verify
  @ball
  @bingo_board.each{|row| p row}
  @bingo_board.collect! { |i| (i == @ball) ? "X" : i}
  end
end


newgame = BingoBoard.new
puts newgame.ball
newgame.verify
```

I am aware that when verify is called it is iterating only through the array1, but I am unsure how to go about making the fix.  Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the root of the problem:

```
@bingo_board.collect! { |i| (i == @ball) ? "X" : i}
```

In this example, i is an array. So what you might want to do is to replace your code with something like:

```
@bingo_board.collect! do |i| # you're iterating over a double array here
   if i.include?(@ball) # i is a single array, so we're checking if the ball number is included
     i[i.index(@ball)] = 'X'; i # find the index of the included element, replace with X
   else
     i
   end
end
```

Or if you prefer one-liner:

```
@bingo_board.collect! { |i| i.include?(@ball) ? (i[i.index(@ball)] = 'X'; i) : i }
```

Be aware that this is going to only replace the first occurrence of the element. So, say if your ball is 10, and you have:

```
[8, 9, 9, 10, 10]
```

you will get:

```
[8, 9, 9, "X", 10]
```

If you want ALL of the 10s to be replaced, then do something like:

```
@bingo_board.collect! do |i|
  if i.include?(@ball)
    i.collect! { |x| x == @ball ? 'X' : x }
  else
    i
  end
end
```

Comment: Consider replacing 'if i.include?(@ball)` with `if ndx = i.index(ball)` (`=`, not `==`).

Comment: Will do but what do you mean by 'ndx'?

Comment: `ndx` will either be `nil` or will equal the index you need in the next line. Probably better to write `ndx = i.index(@ball); i.index(ndx) = 'X' if ndx; i`.

Comment: Thanks the method by daremkd did end up solving the problem.